# How to ignore order in regex?

Tags: regex, validation

I'm using a regex, to validate some stuff in my angular2 application:

```
Validators.pattern('\d*F{1}N{1}K?J?')
```

I just want to allow digits (0-9) and the letters F N K J. K and J should be optional, F and N have to be in there exactly one time.

Does anyone know, how to ignore the order of letters and digits? Not it just matches, if I exactly insert chars in this order: 012FNKJ. KJFN012 doesn't match at all. :(

Comment: have you tried to wrap everything in square brakets `[]` ?

Comment: Can you please provide more clarification what should/should not match? Can you have more than one occurrence of `K` and `J`? What about `F` and `N`? Can all characters be in any order? Can other characters, e.g. whitespace or other letters, be in the string? What about lower case letters? Try to provide a more comprehensive list of matching/non-matching strings.

Comment: Also, do you **need** to use regex for this? It may be simpler, and more performant, to do this with a simple function call.

Comment: Just to be clear, 999999999999999999999999999999F9N99999999999999999999999 is valid right?

Comment: Yep, I need a regex for this, because my customer wants me to use a regex :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative look-ahead combined with a back reference:

```
^(?=.*F)(?=.*N)(?:\d|([FNKJ])(?!.*\1))*$
```

It starts by using look-aheads to make sure the `F` and the `N` are in there.Then it matches digits, **or** a letter from the allowed group **capturing** the letter followed by a negative look-ahead to ensure it doesn't repeat itself. The previous alternative is then repeated, until the end of the string.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GghSMS/3).

Comment: On a performance note, it takes **81 steps** to apply this regex to a simple string like `KJFN012`. A non-regex solution could solve this in a maximum of **7** steps.

Comment: The solution is, admittedly, very clever though :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a **pure regex** answer to your problem (whitespace has been added for improved readability):

```
^
(?=[^F]*F[^F]*$)
(?=[^N]*N[^N]*$)
(?=[^K]*K?[^K]*$)
(?=[^J]*J?[^J]*$)
[FNKJ\d]+$
```

Explanation:

- Each of the four `(?=...)` sections of the pattern are **lookaheads**. They are saying, for example, "the string must contain any number of non-`K`s, then maybe one `K`, then any number more non-`K`s".
- The final part of the regex is saying "the whole string must contain **only** `F`, `N`, `K`, `J` and digits".

---

However, if possible then I would recommend implementing a **non-regex** solution to this problem. My answer above is difficult to understand, and way slower than a simple function could be (`O(n)`!).

Some pseudo-code that solves this without a regex, in `O(n)`:

```
function check_valid(string) {
  found_f = false
  found_n = false
  found_k = false
  found_j = false

  for(letter in string) {
    switch(letter) {
      case 'F':
        if(found_f) { return false }
        found_f = true
        break;
      case 'N':
        if(found_n) { return false }
        found_n = true
        break;
      case 'K':
        if(found_k) { return false }
        found_k = true
        break;
      case 'J':
        if(found_j) { return false }
        found_j = true
        break;
      case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4:
      case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9:
        break;
      default:
        return false; 
    }
  }

  return(found_f & found_n)
}
```

Comment: Wish I could give more than one `+1` for that last part, 'cause that's the most important bit right there. Just because a problem _can_ be solved with a regex, most certainly does not mean that it _should_.

Comment: Where do you get `O(n)!` from? This solution as written is only `O(5n)`, because it is 5 linear scans of the string (exclusive boundaries means no backtracking is done)

Comment: @Tezra I said you could get `O(n)` **if you use a non-regex** solution. I've just updated my answer with such a function, in pseudo-code.

Comment: @TomLord Ah... I still don't agree with that argument though. The regex for this IS linear (only twice the work worst case. same work with a more complex regex using conditionals). So in practice, the only problem with Regex here, is that it it is long/hard-to-read (and thous, a pain to make changes to). In this case, your ONLY concern really should be legibility (as that is the only factor that actually means anything in practice for this scenario)

Comment: @Tezra Your figure of `5n` makes false assumptions about how regex backtracking works. For example, see [this example](https://regex101.com/r/X34QZc/1/), which takes `46` steps to invalidate a `6` letter string (compared to the `6` steps my function would take). If the pattern got more complicated, e.g. "3 or four `F`s", then you could see far worse performance than `5x` slower.

Comment: @Tezra Also, slightly off topic, but [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is a measure of **growth rate**. Because of this, `O(5n) == O(n)` ... But the regex solution is not `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `|` to say "this pattern or this pattern", and explicitly lay out both patterns.

```
[0-9KJ]*F[0-9KJ]*N[0-9KJ]*|[0-9KJ]*N[0-9KJ]*F[0-9KJ]*
```

This is why Regex is not good for fuzzy matching. You'd be better validating with `[0-9FNKJ]*` and `string.containsOne('F', 'N')` (psudo code)

Comment: Even that's nowhere near fuzzy enough, though... The string was supposed to contain **only one** `F` and `N`, whereas you pattern matches e.g. `123FFNN`.

Comment: @TomLord Misread OP, but it's a simple change. The main point is that this loose logic explodes the size of the Regex you need, and there are simpler alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion. It matches "*any string of `K`, `J` and `digits` that contains exactly one `F` and exactly one `N`*".

```
^[KJ0-9]*F[KJ0-9]*N[KJ0-9]*$
```

**Explanation:**

- `[KJ0-9]*` between zero and unlimited times K, J and numbers
- `F[KJ0-9]*` a F followed by K, J and numbers
- `N[KJ0-9]*` a N followed by K, J and numbers

Note that if `N` can be before `F` in your pattern, you may want to use

```
^[KJ0-9]*F[KJ0-9]*N[KJ0-9]*|[KJ0-9]*N[KJ0-9]*F[KJ0-9]*$
```

As you can not make a regex count basically, that is the cleaner way I see to check it with a regex.

#### [Test it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3UmEQ9/2)

Comment: Does not match `123NF`.

Comment: @TomLord it does, if you test it on rexex101. But he should add a `^`  and `$` at the beginning and end to match the entire string

Comment: @PierreDuc You mean updating to [`^[KJ0-9]*F[KJ0-9]*N[KJ0-9]*$|^[KJ0-9]*N[KJ0-9]*F[KJ0-9]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/3UmEQ9/5)?

Comment: ...And your "fixed" version matches things like `FKJJJ` -- which is also wrong, since `J` is supposed to only appear `0` or `1` times. This problem is totally impractical to solve with a regular expression, unless you use look-aheads.

Comment: @Mistalis change it to `^[KJ0-9]*F[KJ0-9]*N[KJ0-9]*|[KJ0-9]*N[KJ0-9]*F[KJ0-9]*$`

Comment: @TomLord It doesn't specify that J should only appear 0 or once

Comment: @PierreDuc That was my interpretation, given that OP used `\d*` and `J?` in their original attempt!